# PHP PDO - output the prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I use a prepared statment wiht PDO. and the method execute.

I want to display the statment before it is executed, with the data replaced - the real 1:1 statment as a string?

Any ideas?

Comment: Show some code, then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Are you using bound parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [PDOStatement::debugDumpParams](http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.debugdumpparams).
Since the parameters are not necessarily mixed into the sql statement at the client-side (i.e. your php script) I suppose that's as close as you can get to what you've asked for.